# ReactiveCocoa - Changing side effects into signals

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

In my application I have a signal which triggers some asynchronous network activity via `flattenMap`. I want to display a loading indicator while the network activity is in progress.

My current solution works just fine:

```
  [[[[self.signInButton
    rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
    doNext:^(id x) {
      // show the loading indicator as a side-effect
      self.loadingIndicator.hidden = NO;
    }]
    flattenMap:^id(id x) {
      return [self doSomethingAsync];
    }]
    subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *result) {
      // hide the indicator again
      self.loadingIndicator.hidden = YES;
      // do something with the results
    }];
```

This works, however I would like to change the above code so that the `hidden` property of the loading indicator can be set via a signal.

Is this possible?

Elsewhere in my app I have more complex requirements where the visibility of an element depends on a few different 'events', being able to compose these via signals would be much better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[RACCommand](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACCommand.h) is tailor-built for exactly this use case, and will usually result in dramatically simpler code than the alternatives:

```
@weakify(self);

RACCommand *signInCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^(id _) {
    @strongify(self);
    return [self doSomethingAsync];
}];

self.signInButton.rac_command = signInCommand;

// Show the loading indicator while signing in.
RAC(self.loadingIndicator, hidden) = [signInCommand.executing not];
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your signal is: when `signInButtonSignal` or `resultSignal` send a value, invert the last value of `hidden`. That's easy enough.

```
[[[hiddenSig replayLast] not] sample:[RACSignal merge:@[signInButtonSignal, resultSignal]];
```

I'm using exactly that construct for a situation similar to yours. It might be nice to wrap it up into an operator:

```
- (RACSignal *)toggle:(RACSignal *)toggler
{
    return [[[self replayLast] not] sample:toggler];
}
```

Then you have just

```
[hiddenSig toggle:[RACSignal merge:@[signInButtonSignal, resultSignal]]];
```

Another possibility might be a class method, tying the state to a mapping Block:

```
+ (RACSignal *)toggle:(RACSignal *)toggler initially:(BOOL)initial
{
    __block BOOL currVal = initial;
    return [[toggler map:^id (id _) {
        currVal = !currVal;
        return @(currVal);
    }] startWith:@(initial)];
}
```

and then

```
[RACSignal toggle:[RACSignal merge:@[signInButtonSignal, resultSignal]]
        initially:NO];
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for that - I'll try to wrap my head around your answer and give it a try shortly. Much appreciated.

Comment: You bet! I'm glad you resurrected this question; I saw it the other day, but you deleted it before I could get back to answer.

Comment: I deleted it because I *thought* I had found the answer, see this issue on github https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/469 however, with RC2.0 some of the techniques described in the answer are no longer available. The breaking wide-spread changes from 1.0-2.0 can make it a bit tricky learn RC ... and with RC3.0 they are planning on continuing the trend with some further big-impact breaking changes. Anyhow - it's a great framework none-the-less.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer from Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21039269/249933) helped quite a bit, but in the end I found a simpler solution. Simply breaking the pipeline into two signals, one for the button press, the other for the subsequent asynchronous activity. I then merged the two to give a signal which I used to bind to the `loadingIndicator`'s `hidden` property:

```
// a signal that triggers sign-in
RACSignal *signInStartSignal = [self.signInButton
                         rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// a signal that emits the sign in result
RACSignal *signInResultSignal =
  [signInStartSignal
    flattenMap:^id(id x) {
      return [self doSomethingAsync];
    }];

[signInResultSignal
  subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *result) {
    // do something based on the result
  }];

// merge the two signals 
RACSignal *signInInProgress =
  [[RACSignal merge:@[signInResultSignal, signInStartSignal]]
    map:^id(id value) {
      // if the signal value is a UIButton, the signal that
      // just fired was the signInStartSignal
      return @(![[value class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIButton class]]);
    }];

RAC(self.signInFailureText,hidden) = signInInProgress;
```

Comment: Merging but distinguishing the two signals and mapping the values to booleans! _Nice_ solution. Very nice.

Comment: Thanks, glad you like it :-)